# EF Core: Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get all my active `Products` (`GetByCategory`), including all active `ProductSpecifications`, with no success.

If I execute the commented block I get the Exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid

My solution was to get all active `Products`, then load all active `ProductSpecifications` using the method

```
LoadAllActiveSpecifications(products)
```

The problem to use `LoadAllActiveSpecifications` is that I need to run a for loop to load all specifications.

Is it possible to load all active `ProductSpecification` implicitly?

Here is my code. Could someone please, tell me what I'm missing?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetByCategory(string code)
{
    /*
    // Following the example from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data
    return await _context
                    .Products
                    .Include(p => p.Category)
                    .Include(product => product
                                            .Specifications
                                            .Where(specification => specification.IsActive))
                    .Where(product => product.IsActive)
                    .Where(p => p.Category.Code == code)
                    .ToListAsync();
    */

    var products = await _context
                            .Products
                            .Include(p => p.Category)
                            //.Include(p => p.Specifications)
                            .Where(p => p.IsActive)
                            .Where(p => p.Category.Code == code)
                            .ToListAsync();

    await LoadAllActiveSpecifications(products);

    return products;
}

private async Task LoadAllActiveSpecifications(List<Product> products)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < products.Count; index++)
    {
        var product = products[index];

        await LoadSpecActiveAsync(product);
    }
}

private async Task LoadSpecActiveAsync(Product product)
{
    await _context
            .Entry(product)
            .Collection(p => p.Specifications)
            .Query()
            .Where(s => s.IsActive)
            .LoadAsync();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: What's the problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: I feel like I've seen this problem before. Have you tried moving the Where clause outside of the Include? Also, if Specifications maps to another table you might need to add a ThenIncludes before the Where

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I was getting that error System.InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid. Thanks

Comment: hey @DillonDrobena, I tried both and didn't work. The solution for my case was to set a Global Filter on my Context like that: `modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSpecification>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.IsActive);` as Steve post the link. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF by definition will load a complete graph of entities. You can assign global query filters in EF Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) to handle rules for things like soft deletes which will allow EF to return just "Active" rows for applicable entities.  EF6 had something similar in Dynamic Queries.

Comment: Thanks @steve-py . I set Filter as the link and it worked like a charm. Here is the solution for my case: `modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSpecification>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.IsActive);`